# I don't understand the usage of 'Lambda' and 'Transform' and from this code (pandas docs)

Tags: pandas, lambda, transform

I am scouring the pandas docs to try to understand how transform is used and can upon this example from the docs:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html (under 'Transformation")

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



index = pd.date_range('10/1/1999', periods=1100)
ts = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0.5, 2, 1100), index)

ts = ts.rolling(window=100,min_periods=100).mean().dropna()
key = lambda x: x.year

zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()


transformed = ts.groupby(key).transform(zscore)
```

A couple of things I'm confused about; first the usage of  lambda.

```
key = lambda x: x.year
```

What datatype is x supposed to represent in this case? I'm unsure of which datatypes allow the call of the attribute ".year"

As for this case:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
```

x is going to be representing each row of ts (of ts.roll?) and x.mean is the mean of what exactly?

Finally, what exactly does transform do in the last line?
Is it just replacing the values of ts with zscore?
I ran the variable "transformed" but the index (dates) look the same as ts' index. So what exactly did groupby(key) do in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: For key, x is the index and the lambda function returns years of the time stamps in the index. For zscore, x is the slice of the series sliced by year.

Comment: Hi piRSquared. " x is the slice of the series sliced by year.". So I'm assuming the x.mean is the mean of the whole slice(group), while x will represent just one element of that slice. For example the group '2000 '(Year 2000) has many values. So x will represent each element of that group via iteration?

Comment: nope. x is the whole group. That's how x.mean() returns the mean of the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `key = lambda x: x.year` implies that your index is of `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

this would call the year of each index and group the df by year.

now that you have a groupby object you can transform each group:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
```

will take each group (that would be each year) calculate the mean (`x.mean()`), the standard deviation (`x.std()`) and apply the formula  `(x - x.mean()) / x.std()` for each data point.

so doing this:

```
 ts.groupby(key).mean()
Out[274]: 
2000   0.4851
2001   0.2568
2002   0.4544
```

return the mean for each year, and doing this:

```
ts.groupby(key).std()
Out[275]: 
2000   0.1969
2001   0.1539
2002   0.1881
```

return the standard deviation for each year

transform will apply this to each row, so let's use position 1 for a test

```
ts.head()
Out[277]: 
2000-01-08   0.7562
2000-01-09   0.7639
2000-01-10   0.7020
2000-01-11   0.6970
2000-01-12   0.6906
```

since the first index is of year 2000, we need to use the mean and std of that group such has: 0.7562- 0.4851 / 0.1969 = 1.3767

```
ts.groupby(key).transform(zscore).head(2)
Out[282]: 
2000-01-08   1.3767
2000-01-09   1.4159
```

Comment: Hi Steven. So  if x.mean is the mean of the values of  whole group (which is grouped by year), does x represent just each element (each value) of the group. Essentially, x is iterating through each value of each group and subtracting by that group's mean? Thanks.

Comment: Ah!　Got i! I was confused about  how transformed is being applied, and you explanation(by rows) cleared up that confusion. Thank you so much.